# Check of step in proof that open subsets of the real numbers can be expressed as unions of disjoint open intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The following is from "An Introduction to Lebesgue Integration and Fourier Series" by Howard J. Wilcox and David L. Myers:

7.2 Theorem: Every non-empty open set $G \subset \mathbb{R}$ can be expressed uniquely as a finite or countably infinite union of pairwise disjoint open intervals.

Proof: Suppose first that $G$ is bounded. Since $G$ is open, for each $x \in G$ there is an open subinterval of $G$ containing $x$. Let $b_{x} = \mathrm{lub} \{y \mid (x,y) \subset G\}$, and $a_{x} = \mathrm{glb} \{z \mid (z,x) \subset G\}$. Let $I_{x} = (a_{x}, b_{x})$, called the component of $x$ in $G$. Clearly $x \in I_{x}$.

Now $I_{x} \subset G$, for if $w \in I_{x}$, say $x < w < b_{x}$, then by definition of $b_{x}$, there is a number $y$ such that $w < y$ and $(x,y) \subset G$. Hence $w \in G$. The case where $a_{x} < w < x$ is handled similarly. (What about $w = x$?)

Also $a_{x} \notin G$ and $b_{x} \notin G$ (see exercise 9.10).

I am attempting Exercise 9.10: Prove that $a_{x} \notin G$, in the proof of Theorem 7.2.

This is my attempt:

Suppose for contradiction that $a_{x} \in G$. Since $G$ is open, then there exists an open subinterval $(\alpha, \beta) \subset G$ containing $a_{x}$. Since $(a_{x}, x) \subset I_{x}$, and $I_{x} \subset G$, then $(a_{x}, x) \subset G$. Then since $(\alpha, a_{x}) \subset G$, and $a_{x} \in G$ by assumption, then $(\alpha, x) \subset G$. Then $\alpha \in \{z \mid (z,x) \subset G\}$. Then since $\alpha < a_{x}$, and $a_{x}$ is a lower bound of $\{z \mid (z,x) \subset G\}$, this is a contradiction.

Is this correct? Is there a simpler or more elegant proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW your proof seems fine to me. It's straightforward and it efficiently uses what is necessary for the proof without anything extraneous. Personally I can't think of a significantly better approach.

Answer (score -1):

A simple proof.

Notation. For $x,y\in \Bbb R$ let $In[x,y]=[x,y]\cup [y,x]=[\min(x,y),\max (x,y)]$.

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\Bbb R.$ For $x,y\in G$ let $x\sim y$ iff $In[x,y]\subset G.$

Obviously $\sim$ is symmetric and reflexive on $G.$ Exercise: Show that $\sim$ is transitive on G. Hint: $In[x,y]\cup In[y,z]=In[\min(x,y,z),\max(x,y,z)]$ for all $x,y,z\in \Bbb R.$

So $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $G.$ For $x\in G$ let $[x]_{\sim}=\{y\in G:y\sim x\}.$ Exercise: $[x]_{\sim}$ is convex for each $x\in G.$

Now the set $G_{/\sim}=\{[x]_{\sim}:x\in G\}$ of $\sim$-equivalence classes is a partition of $G.$  And each $[x]_{\sim}$  is open, because if $x\in G$ then $(-r+x,r+x)\subset G$ for some $r>0,$ so $y\sim x$ for all $y \in (-r+x,r+x).$

Therefore $G_{/\sim}$ is  a partition of $G$ into a family of pair-wise disjoint non-empty convex open sets.

$Any$ family $F$ of pair-wise disjoint non-empty open subsets of $\Bbb R$ is countable because $\Bbb R$ has a countable dense subset. For example, for each $f\in F$ let $\psi(f)\in f\cap \Bbb Q.$ Then $\psi:F\to \Bbb Q $ is injective, so $F$ is countable.

Therefore $G_{/\sim}$ is countable.

Remark. The notation $In[x,y]$ is ad hoc. I just found it convenient, that you don't need to distinguish the cases $x<y,x=y,$ or $x>y $.

Comment: Quotes: "Check of step in proof that..." "Is this correct?"

Comment: @Did "Is there a simpler or more elegant proof?"

Comment: Do you think you answered the question? And even about what **is** in your post: why would this alternative proof be "simpler or more elegant"? Again, not a word about this aspect.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant a simpler or more elegant proof of just Exercise 9.10.